# Who Gets the semaphore cond_wait or pthread_mutex_lock

Tags: c, multithreading

Thread_2 is looping to get the semaphore:

```
for(;;){
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
}
```

Thread_3 is waiting for signal condition:

```
for(;;){
        pthread_cond_wait( &cond, &mutex ); 
}
```

Thread_1 releases the semaphore:

```
for(;;){    
    pthread_cond_signal( &cond ); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex ); 
}
```

What if thread_2 get the semaphore before thread_3, what would happened to thread_2?

Comment: Add language tag, please.

Comment: Also, provide example code to illustrate your question.  It is not clear what you mean by "looping to get the semaphore" for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be answered by looking only at thread 2.

```
for(;;){
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
}
```

If the mutex is never released by any other thread, then thread two will block forever in its first call to `pthread_mutex_lock`. Otherwise, if this thread ever acquires the lock, it will call `pthread_mutex_lock` while already holding the lock. What happens next depends on the type of mutex this is:

1. If this is a recursive mutex, thread 2 will continue to increase its holding count on the mutex. No other thread will ever get the mutex since thread 2 will never exit its loop.
2. If this is not a recursive mutex, the behavior is undefined as thread 2 calls a function in violation of its pre-condition. You are not permitted to call `pthread_mutex_lock` if you already hold the lock you are trying to acquire and the lock is not recursive.

From an earlier edit of the question:

> I read that when it gets the condition signal, it locks the semaphore, but the semaphore already grabbed by thread 2?

The operation of locking a mutex blocks until the mutex can be acquired. If another thread already holds the mutex, the thread blocked on the condition variable will change to being blocked on the mutex and will contend for it (possibly along with other waiting threads) when it is unlocked.